# Split long conditional expressions to lines

Tags: python, if-statement, python-2.6

I have some if statements like:

```
def is_valid(self):
    if (self.expires is None or datetime.now() < self.expires)
    and (self.remains is None or self.remains > 0):
        return True
    return False
```

When I type this expressions my Vim automatically moves `and` to new line with this same indent as `if` line . I try more indent combinations, but validating always says thats invalid syntax. How to build long if's?

Comment: Just a comment, there's no need to have an `if` statement in your example.  You could just `return (self.expires is None or datetime.now() ...)`

Comment: I just learning Python and I suppose I can do that but dont feel so good. Thanks mgilson

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Add an additional level of brackets around the whole condition. This will allow you to insert line breaks as you wish.

```
if (1+1==2
  and 2 < 5 < 7
  and 2 != 3):
    print 'yay'
```

Regarding the actual number of spaces to use, the [Python Style Guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) doesn't mandate anything but gives some ideas:

```
# No extra indentation.
if (this_is_one_thing and
    that_is_another_thing):
    do_something()

# Add a comment, which will provide some distinction in editors
# supporting syntax highlighting.
if (this_is_one_thing and
    that_is_another_thing):
    # Since both conditions are true, we can frobnicate.
    do_something()

# Add some extra indentation on the conditional continuation line.
if (this_is_one_thing
        and that_is_another_thing):
    do_something()
```

Answer (score 3):

put the linebreaks inside brackets
`if ((....) and (...)):`

Answer (score 3):

You could *invert* the tests and return False on sub-sets of the test:

```
def is_valid(self):
    if self.expires is not None and datetime.now() >= self.expires:
        return False
    if self.remains is not None and self.remains <= 0:
        return False
    return True
```

This way you can break up the long line of tests and make the whole thing a lot more readable.

Yes, you can use additional parentheses around your boolean tests to allow for newlines in the test, but readability suffers greatly when you have to go across multiple lines.

Comment: Thanks, but is this really more readable? One `if` logically breaked is more readable for me - I can treat it like many ifs with shared result statement.

Comment: Yes, absolutely. You have 2 logically unrelated reasons for your content to be invalid. Either it has expired, or remains has reached 0. What if in the future there are more reasons? Keeping these separated increases readability and maintainability.

Comment: BTW please don't try "mixed" cascades like `if A: return False / if B: return True / if C: return False / return True`, they read much worse and are much better of written with parentheses.